# Как перевернуть текст на кнопке?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как перевернуть текст на кнопке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть способы(перевернуть HDC(контекст), например), но они очень уж сложные(юзая WinApi). А так, советую для этих целей использовать либо компонент "**Tbitbtn**" с вкладки "Additional", либо простой "**Timage**" с той же вкладки.